# How to output contents of rotating log files dynamically to stdout?

Tags: tail

I want to output the contents of a number of rotating log files, let's say `file.log.1` and `file.log` to stdout for continued processing.

For a single log file I could have used `tail -F file.log`, but since I want to include the contents of the old log file as well: Is there a good way to do this without a temporary file?

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be as simple as:

```
(cat file.log.1;tail -F file.log)
```

This will work with e.g `grep`:

```
(cat file.log.1;tail -F file.log) | grep pattern
```

And for multiple log files, this will give the contents of all files in order, and the last file being monitored for new entries.

```
(cat file.log.{10..1};tail -F file.log) | grep pattern
```